# Serializing a nested sealed class in Kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

I am trying to serialize a nested `sealed class`. Here is an example

```kotlin
@Serializable
sealed class Base {
    @SerialName("concrete_property")
    val concreteProperty: String = "concrete property of base"
    @SerialName("abstract_property")
    val abstractProperty: String

    @Serializable
    @SerialName("subclass")
    data class Subclass (
        override abstractProperty: String
        @SerialName("subclass_concrete_property")
        val subclassConcreteProperty: String
    ) : Base()

    @Serializable
    @SerialName("subclass2")
    data class Subclass2 (
        override abstractProperty: String
        @SerialName("subclass_other_concrete_property")
        val subclassOtherConcreteProperty: String
    ) : Base()
}
```

Then for example what I would like to happen is:

```kotlin
val baseInstance = Base.Subclass(abstractProperty = "abstp", subclassConcreteProperty = "sclassp")

print(
      Json{
        encodeDefaults = true // can check https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/polymorphism.md#concrete-properties-in-a-base-class
      }.encodeToString(base) 
)

// Result: {"abstractProperty": "abstp", "abstract_property": "abstp", "subclassConcreteProperty": "sclassp", "concreteProperty":"concrete property of base", }
```

The issue I am currently facing lies in the `@SerialName` of `abstractProperty`. Is there a way to make serialzer take one from base class so it is `abstract_property` instead of `abstractProperty`.

Of course I understand that I can add `@SerialName` in the subclass explicitly but I really don't want to repeat this code yet again. I assume I will have many subclasses with the same `@SerialName` for this abstract property.

Comment: Try to search Polimorphic serialization, unfortunately not remember the exact way, but this will help you to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this without specifying anything but `@Serializable` for subclasses is to use a [`sealed`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/polymorphism.md#sealed-classes) supertype.

If you can't or won't do that, you'll have to specify [`@SerialName`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/polymorphism.md#open-polymorphism) for each supported subclass. Which is logical, because how should the compiler plugin know about arbitrary subclasses if you don't mark them?

It's all explained at length in [the documentation](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/polymorphism.md).